# \frac function - file not found

Tags: xfrac

Is there anyone who knows why my `\frac` function does not work? Is there a problem with notation?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[•]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\\

\section*{Question4}
\gg\)is a monotone preference \rightarrow ||y-x|| \leq \epsilon ,\forall \epsilon \textgreater\) 0 and $y \textgreater x$\.
\\
\textbf{Proof}\\

Given $x\) \in $X\) \subseteq $R^L$) and  \forall \epsilon \textgreater\) 0. \\

Let e \eq (1,2....,l) \in $R^L$) and let $y \eq x$) + \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{L}} e$)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `\usepackage[•]{graphicx}`??? The given example is neither complete nor compilable at all

Comment: Nothing "works" in that document: 1) apart from the curious option passed to `graphicx` that ChristianHupfer mentioned, 2) your math. expressions are not in math. environments, as they should, 3) you use a weird combination of `\(`, `\)` and `$` to close and open your math environments, and 4) the `\eq` command is not defined. You should try to learn what are the math environment made for in Latex, for instance by reading http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX%3aMath

Comment: Also you should read up on how to do norms, hint `||x||` is not correct

Comment: And ... use `\mathbb{R}^L` instead of R^L

Answer (score 1):

Inline math is `$ math expression $`. For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

    Given $x \in X \subseteq R^L$ and  $\forall \epsilon > 0$. 

    Let $e = (1,2....,l) \in R^L$ and let $y = x + \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{L}} e$

\end{document}
```

[image]

And don't use all that `\\`.